# CSS Grid element centered on desktop but not on mobile

Tags: css, google-chrome, mobile, grid-layout

I have a problem with CSS Grid element on my webpage. On a desktop it looks as it should, but when I open the page on my smarthphone in chrome the content .scores element is not verticaly centered. The borders are there just for better visualization. See the image https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eyEb5WPm0rwsKXL6n0M5V263MzTr9A0k/view?usp=sharing or look on the live page here https://tomas-kahanek.eu/hra/

Tried to emulate it on desktop but without any luck so I would guess it is related to the mobile browser. Right now I don't have any media queries in place.

```css
.score-board {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-template-columns: 45% auto 45%;
  grid-template-areas: "user separator computer" "ulabel separator clabel";
  background-color: $digital-green;
  color: $digital-black;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px -1px black inset;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.scores {
  font-size: 7rem;
  font-family: $digital;
  line-height: 7rem;
  border: 1px solid black;
  align-self: center;
}

.user-score-wrapper {
  grid-area: user;
}

.computer-score-wrapper {
  grid-area: computer;
}

#user-label {
  grid-area: ulabel;
  font-family: $digital;
}

#comp-label {
  grid-area: clabel;
  font-family: $digital;
}

.separator {
  grid-area: separator;
  font-size: 4rem;
  font-family: $digital;
  align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<section class="score-board">
  <div class="user-score-wrapper">
    <div id="user-score" class="scores">0</div>
    <div id="user-label">HUMAN</div>
  </div>
  <div class="separator">:</div>
  <div class="computer-score-wrapper">
    <div id="computer-score" class="scores">0</div>
    <div id="comp-label">COMPUTER</div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Would like to know if this is some kind of a bug, or I am missing something. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I see the problem you describe, but the code you posted doesn't reproduce it. You should post enough code to reproduce more of the layout. Also, I noticed you haven't used heights anywhere. Try posting a defined height on a container and see if that works.

Comment: Your posted code in a demo: https://jsfiddle.net/n0r1sgcu/2/

Comment: Here is the demo: https://jsfiddle.net/f5okyhd3/1/ but it is not 100% true to the original page (link included in the text), since the font is missing. Also as I stated before I get this behavior only in mobile browsers. To me it seems they don't use the align-self: center property.

Comment: That fiddle demo works fine in my mobile Chrome browser.

Comment: It does work for me too, so maybe it is related to the font I'm using.

Comment: So I switch to another font and I got rid of the inconsistency on mobile browsers.